# Как открыть метод доставки только в том случае, если в корзине есть определенная сумма?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем здравствуйте! Возникла такая проблема: нужно скрывать метод доставки , пока в корзине сайта не наберется товара на сумму 5000 р. Я перерыл кучу инфы, но нигде ответа нет. Я понимаю , мне нужно найти переменную , где хранится общая сумма? Как это реализовать подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_on_price', 10, 2 );
function shipping_on_price( $rates, $package ) {

   $total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
   //echo $total;
   if( $total <= 5000 ) {

      unset( $rates['flat_rate'] );
      unset( $rates['free_shipping'] );
      // and other what you want to hide

   }
return $rates;
}
```

Comment: Почему ваш ответ не на русском?

Comment: Привык писать на английском)